# How to add tooltip on magento 2 checkout, on street address field?

Tags: forms, magento, checkout

I want to add tooltip on street address field, on magento 2 checkout page.
I tried adding it in: vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="street" xsi:type="array"> 
   <item name="config" xsi:type="array"> 
      <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array"> 
        <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">For delivery address verification.</item> 
      </item> 
   </item> 
</item>
```

Comment: Hi Arsalan Ul Haq, what have you tried already? Can you provide some code? Please take same time to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section.

Comment: I tried some wild guesses and made a look around web, but failed to so. I just want to add a tooltip (help icon) on magento 2's checkout page after street addresses field. Also I tried adding like this:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `after plugin` to add tooltip to street fields, you need to inject checkout LayoutProcessor

```
Class LayoutProcessor
{
 /**
  * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
  * @param array $jsLayout
  * @return array
 */
 public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
  ) {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children'][0]['tooltip']['description'] = "ToolTip 1";
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children'][1]['tooltip']['description'] = "ToolTip 2";

    return $jsLayout;
 }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Please refer this [POST](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227762/create-plugin-layoutprocessorprocess-vs-override-checkout-index-index-xml)

Comment: Not working. I added a di.xml file and your file, than ran upgrade and static content commands, but not helpful

Comment: @ArsalanUlHaq maybe you don't know how to inject it, if so you can clearly say..you can not say it's not working. I have posted a screenshot.

Comment: please tell me how to inject it? It will be really helpful

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="sr_ModuleName_checkout_layout_processor"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>

should I inject it like this?

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked. I somehow managed to learn injecting it. and it worked. Again Thanks.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar your code only for shipping not billing can you tell me how to add for billing

Comment: @PawankumarN `print_r($jsLayout)` and you will see the billing step , you can add there same as above.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']['cashondelivery-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['street'][0]
            ['notice'] = __('This is my custom notice.'); but it not wokring